# cheese doesn't work in beagleboneblack installed with angstrom, using chipsee LCD

Tags: camera, angstrom, v4l

I am using chipsee LCD + beaglebone black and Logitech Webcam C270. I am using the Angstrom OS distribution provided by Chipsee.
I wanted to use Cheese to see if the webcam works fine or not.
When I open cheese, it opens and shows a waiting animation and then closes without any error messages or anything.

Any suggestions/pointers for debugging this issue?

Adding `journalctl -a -f` output when I run cheese

```
 Jul 19 16:01:05 beaglebone-exp kernel: usb 2-1: reset high-speed USB device number 14 using musb-hdrc
Jul 19 16:01:05 beaglebone-exp kernel: usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 14
Jul 19 16:01:06 beaglebone-exp kernel: usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 15 using musb-hdrc
Jul 19 16:01:06 beaglebone-exp kernel: usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=0825
Jul 19 16:01:06 beaglebone-exp kernel: usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=2
Jul 19 16:01:06 beaglebone-exp kernel: usb 2-1: SerialNumber: FD382030
Jul 19 16:01:06 beaglebone-exp kernel: uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device <unnamed> (046d:0825)
Jul 19 16:01:06 beaglebone-exp kernel: input: UVC Camera (046d:0825) as /devices/ocp.3/47400000.usb/musb-hdrc.1.auto/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/input/input17
```